# weird SCNGeometryElement count of a box

Tags: geometry, scenekit

I'm coloring each side of a box with different color using materials property. The code works and the box is beautifully colored. The documentation states the following:

> For geometries with multiple elements, you can use the materials
>   property to attach different materials to each element.

I'm testing the number of geometry elements of a box (cube). The result is 1.I'm a little confused about the meaning of geometry element. Why can I use the materials property to attach different materials if the box only has 1 geometry element?

```
//cretaing a box
        let box = SCNBox(width: 40, height: 40, length: 40, chamferRadius: 0)
        boxNode.geometry = box
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
        boxNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, -90, 0)
        boxNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 1, 0, 1)
//setting up materials
        let mat1 = SCNMaterial()
        mat1.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()
        let mat2 = SCNMaterial()
        mat2.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blueColor()
        let mat3 = SCNMaterial()
        mat3.diffuse.contents = UIColor.greenColor()
        let mat4 = SCNMaterial()
        mat4.diffuse.contents = UIColor.yellowColor()
        let mat5 = SCNMaterial()
        mat5.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blackColor()
        let mat6 = SCNMaterial()
        mat6.diffuse.contents = UIColor.orangeColor()
        box.materials = [mat1,mat2,mat3,mat4,mat5,mat6]
//checking the number of geometry elements
        let i = box.geometryElementCount
        println("Number of geometry elements: \(i)")
        animateBox()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for SCNGeometry / SCNMaterial is correct.

But SCNBox will automatically generate from 1 to 6 geometryElements depending on the number of material you assign to it. And this will be done just before the rendering so depending on when you ask for the number of geometry elements, you may get different results.

Only SCNBox does this. Other primitives and other geometry don't have such dynamic number of geometry element.